# Conjoining an array in English

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Is there a ready made library/method that serializes an array into a string as follows?

```
[] #=> ""
["Peter"] #=> "Peter"
["Peter", "Paul"] #=> "Peter and Paul"
["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"] #=> "Peter, Paul, and Mary" (with Oxford comma)
["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"] #=> "Peter, Paul and Mary" (without Oxford comma)
```

If not, what is the shortest way to do this? I would like it in this form:

```
class Array
    def conjoin oxford_comma = true
        ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/conversions'

["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"].to_sentence
=> "Peter, Paul, and Mary"
```

or without an oxford comma.

```
["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"].to_sentence(:last_word_connector => ' and ')
=> "Peter, Paul and Mary"
```

Here's more info from 
[apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Conversions/to_sentence)

Also note, that if you're using rails, at least, you can control this from a [language file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L30) using [i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to avoid duplicating, or adding complexity to, this logic.